# External hard drive is not connected but still showing in Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility

I've noticed multiple copies of one of my external hard drives (that i replaced recently) showing up in Disk Utility.
[image]

Does anyone know how to remove them? I no longer have the original external hard drive.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!